# URLSession throws conversion error in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, nsurlsession

I just downloaded Xcode8 and now the previously functional code:

```
let Task = URLSession.sharedSession.dataTaskWithRequest(Request) {

   (data : NSData!, response : URLResponse!, error : NSError!) in

}
```

throws the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(NSData!, URLResponse!, NSError!) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'
```

What is faulty or has changed from Xcode 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give them the optional('?') rather then forcing them they seem to operate without any problem:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: Request) {

    (data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error : Error?) in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message simply says that the compiler wants

```
let task = URLSession.sharedSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

   (data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error : Error?) in

}
```

but you don't need the type annotations at all which magically avoids the error

```
let task = URLSession.sharedSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

   (data, response, error) in

}
```

However in Swift 3 you have to write

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in ... }
```